# Repository error when updating apt

Tags: apt, repository

I have tried to install an app called i-nex (cpu temp monitoring tool) but I couldn't because the package could not be found. However, it has left some remarks on the system. Now, when I try to update apt, I get below errors. How do I get rid of this?

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/i-nex-development-team/daily/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/i-nex-development-team/daily/ubuntu zesty InRelease' is not signed.
```

Comment: Why are you using `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Maybe LB Did It I have no idea. I just copy and paste what I see on the internet.

Comment: @N0rbert Ubuntu version was 20.04.2 LTS when I last checked. Why is everyone asking that?

Comment: Your output says `zesty`, which is a long-dead release of Ubuntu. Were you actually running that particular release, your answer would be much more catastrophic. That's why we ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PPA from your link does not have any published packages for any Ubuntu version, including 20.04 LTS. Moreover the mentioned team does not publish [packages anymore](https://launchpad.net/%7Ei-nex-development-team/+archive/ubuntu/i-nex). Also it is strange that you have *zesty* (= 17.04 , EOL) version in sources.list . So you have to disable this problematic PPA.

As alternative you can get the I-Nex from [different PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eroguescholar/+archive/ubuntu/daily?field.series_filter=focal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:roguescholar/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i-nex
```

Comment: Awesome help. Thank you.